# Sections of "forgetful" projections between flag manifolds

Tags: grassmannians, spin-geometry, steiner-triple-system

Given a subset $S\subseteq\{1,\cdots,n\}$ there is an associated flag manifold $F(S)$. Whenever $A\subseteq B$ there is a "forgetful" projection $F(A)\leftarrow F(B)$ (in fact I think its fibers are direct products of flag manifolds). Due to the following examples, I am curious when these projectios have sections:

- From complex vector spaces, we get sections $F(1,2n)\to F(1,2,2n)$.
- From quaternionic vector spaces, we get $F(1,4n)\to F(1,2,3,4,4n)$.
- More generally, I believe we get $F(1,n)\to F(1,2,\cdots,\rho(n),n)$ for spin representations, where $\rho(n)$ is the max number of linearly independent vector fields on a sphere $S^{n-1}$.
- From the exotic seven-dimensional binary and eight-dimensional ternary cross products we get the two sections $F(2,7)\to F(2,3,7)$ and $F(3,8)\to F(3,4,8)$.

The last example is suggestive: looking at coordinate axes, the sections induce the two Steiner triple systems $S(2,3,7)$ and $S(3,4,8)$. The other sections of $F(1,2n)\to F(1,2,2n)$ and $F(1,4n)\to F(1,k,4n)$ (for any of $k\in\{2,3,4\}$) induce boring Steiner triples.

**Q1**. Is every Steiner triple induced from a section of flag manifolds in this manner?

**Q2**. Does every section of flag manifolds have a "discrete" version on coordinate axes?

**Q3**. Are there any general results on when these sections exist and what shape they take?

*Bonus*. Is anything different if we consider oriented flag manifolds?

For (Q1), perhaps the first thing to consider would be the triple $S(2,3,9)$, the collection of affine lines in $\mathbb{F}_3^2$. Maybe it can be "linearized" via a map $\mathbb{R}X\otimes \mathbb{R}X\to \mathbb{R}X$ (where $X=\mathbb{F}_3^2$) much like the case of cross products. For (Q2), a priori it doesn't seem like we know there exists coordinates which the section plays nice with (i.e. sends coordinate subspaces to coordinate subspaces).